# Have I been removed?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation decrease citing “User was removed”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed)

When hovering over my name,  I just noticed that I have lost 110 reputation points and the sinister explanation is "User was removed".
I don't care much about the lost points but the "removed " part is worrying . What's going on?

**Edit**
So it seems that some   user was removed.
If the removal was voluntary, would it be ill-mannered to ask who my and some others users' benefactor [:-)] was?

Comment: I also lost some rep due to that today. I wonder who was removed.

Comment: Well, I can still see you :)

Comment: See [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it) at meta.SO or
[Reputation decrease citing “User was removed”](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed)  here.

Comment: Thanks for the link,@Martin.

Comment: I've gained -98.

Comment: The same thing happened to me...

Comment: Interesting that I too lost exactly 110 points. :) Wondering who the user is...

Comment: I lost 10.  Must have been an active user while he/she was here!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that another user has been removed, cancelling the upvotes the user has issued, thus negating the reputation they had given you. I too lost reputation today for that reason.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I'm selfishly reassured. But on the other hand, why was *that* user removed? We do agree that (s)he had shown excellent judgment, don't we Alex? :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Apparently, the removal was at the user's own request. That doesn't really answer the question "why?" but it's as close as we'll be able to come without risking stalking charges.

Comment: Thanks, Cameron.I quite agree with you that we shouldn't insist on knowing "why?" if the user doesn't choose to tell us.