# In which condition a user should be removed?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation decrease citing “User was removed”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed)

Some times I saw a notice in Reputation that a user was removed at the same time reputations changed by him were cleared. But how did they be removed?  Did they break the law? Or kept inactive a month?

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: See, for example, [Removing of users](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/removing-of-users). (I've sent the same comment once again, the first time I've forgotten to add http and link did not render.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Users have been removed, for as long as I have been a moderator, exclusively because *they* wanted to be removed —apart from a few obvious spammers, that is.