# What does "user was removed" mean in my 'reputation' history?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation decrease citing “User was removed”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed)

I see a -20 decrement of **'reputation'** for October 6, and the text next to it just says "user was removed." However, my username, question history, etc., all seem to be intact. What is this mysterious -20 from, and what is it referring to when it says that 'user was removed'?

Comment: It is not karma.

Comment: YOu think it is strange to call those points *reputation*, life transcending *karma* is fine...

Comment: I'm just going by what it's called at [LessWrong](http://www.lesswrong.com). I never bothered to look at what it's called at Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Human rationality? Is that like taking a quotient of two human integers, where the denominator is nonzero?

Comment: See [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it) at meta.SO or [Reputation decrease citing “User was removed”](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed) and [Have I been removed?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/have-i-been-removed) here.

Comment: you lucky, I have a -430 and I don't know what anser was removed. An administrator can rest my points and show that message and I will never know if this is from true (like happens in StackOverflow)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that a user was removed. This removes all posts they own with negative total score, possibly including questions that you answered and received upvotes on. (Also, it's called "reputation" here, not karma.)

Comment: I see. So another user removed the account, leading to losing karma I may have accrued from answering posts of theirs. Thank you.

Comment: @EMS, not karma.

Answer (score 1):

If  users are deleted, all their votes are deleted with them. So if they have upvoted you, those votes will be lost and you'll lose the reputation you gained from them.

Comment: Seems, one can also *win* with that deleting of users. Just got 61 points for don't-know-for-what in the previous hour - it even does not appear in the reputation-history ...