# We do loss points when users are removed?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation decrease citing “User was removed”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed)

I realized that I've been rated negatively -5, I didn't understand, when I seek why, I found this:

> -5 User was removed

Why? someone can help me?

thanks

Comment: This has been discussed quite a few times here. you should search a bit in meta to see what has been said on the matter.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez sorry, do you have a link, thank you.

Comment: You can use the search tool :-) If you practice using it, you'll find things much faster! You can also search using google by appending «site:met.math.stackexchange.com» to your keywords.

Comment: Related questions:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6182/user-was-removed, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/users-were-removed, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/have-i-been-removed, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6791/user-was-removed-again, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5122/removal-of-votes-when-a-user-is-removed

Comment: There goes the learning opportunity! :-)

Comment: @EricNaslund Thank you!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez lol to be sincere I have to use more meta search, I'm a little bit lazy on meta site.

Comment: @RafaelChavez: I found all of the above results (and two more) by simply searching "removed." The search on the meta site is actually quite good because overall there are not many posts.

Comment: @EricNaslund yes, my mistake, I'll try to avoid this next time, thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

When a user is deleted, his votes are undone.