# Is it possible to store the good questions and answers of those users who has left or being removed by some reasons?

Tags: discussion, support, faq-proposed, proposal

I want to ask a question to the moderators and the other higher authorities of Math Stack Exchange.

> **Question:** Is it possible to store the good questions and answers of those users who has left or being removed by some reasons ?

Actually, I think, it is helpful for those who answer the questions or discuss about the questions and the answers. We are working hard to give an answer or make a proper discussion. Now, after some times if our work was not displayed on the site (by the reason of others), then there is no worth of our hard work. If it is possible to store the questions and answers, then it will help the interested persons for years and years.

I think my question is understandable to all of you. Please shed light on this matter.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If an answer of yours has been deleted, and you think that your answer would "help interested persons for years and years," then you can post a request to undelete your answer, where you can make a case for its longterm value.

Comment: What is the process to do such case ? Where I post the request to undelete my answer ?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today

Comment: Now come to an important point. How do I get the link that I have to post ?  Because there is only one information that had been provided to me that my reputation is decrease due to "User was removed (learn more) ". As per I found, the link provided by "learn more" have not provide any information about that.

Comment: If a user was removed, that doesn't necessarily mean an answer of yours was removed. It could mean that the user gave you an upvote, and when the user was removed, that upvote was also removed, but the question wasn't deleted, because the question wasn't posted by that user. Now, on your Activity tab, if you click to show your answers, then scroll down to the bottom and click on Show Deleted Answers, you get "Recently Deleted Answers This page shows answers you posted that were deleted in the last 60 days. This includes answers to questions that were deleted." which might help.

Comment: Okay, I will follow your instructions. Thanks

Comment: You can find some information on the reputation decrease for this reason, here: [Reputation decrease citing “User was removed”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3858) (and also in [other linked questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3858)).