# User removed along with link OR how to find out which of my postings' points were affected by the deletion of a user.

Tags: support, reputation, users

At 19 hrs-02 mins yesterday a user was removed with points 2-10=-8 net on it.

If clicked on the link it does not link  to  the question/answer.

How to obtain the reference? Thanks.

Comment: It's unlikely anyone with a similar question will think it is this one.  Perhaps change the Title to something like "*How to find out which of my postings' points were affected by the deletion of a user?*".

Comment: Thanks. Adopted your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

When a user gets removed you only get the information regarding the changes of the points.

You do not get the information on which posts the events occurred or which users was removed.

Using standard functionality of the site, it is not possible to do what you want to do.

Let me add that in comments by Martin Sleziak, and the duplicates, it is explained how one can still find this information.

Comment: It seems that this can be found out using the API. Downloading a user's post scores from SEDE now and after the next update could also be a viable option. See: [Is it possible to know which posts were affected by user removal?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3857) and [Can I know where I lost my reputation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21831)

Comment: I had not know that even though it came up here. It seems almost like a bug that this is exposed.

Comment: I am not sure why it should be considered a bug. If somebody regularly saves their scores (or their [reputation breakdown](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation)), they would be able to get this information. So it is possible to obtain this from publicly available information - assuming the additional effort to save the current status regularly.

Comment: My thinking is that varied arguments were made why it should not be available. I understand that it could be obtained by considering the "difference" between snapshots and that's somewhat unavoidable but that it is explicitly there is surprising. I mean then why not provide it via the link? It's a question that comes up often.

Comment: My bad - I probably missed discussions where there were some arguments why this should be hidden. (Or maybe I saw them and forgot.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. Maybe we are talking at crossed purposes. In both threads you link to there is an answer saying what I mean to say.

Comment: You're right - I was so focused on searching for older posts showing *how* to do it (which I remembered), that I somehow ignored the other answers in those threads. (I probably read those answers when those questions were posted - but I managed to forget about them.) Sorry for many comments which could have been avoided if I *thouroughly* read the links which I posted myself.

Comment: Oh, no! quid has answered a question that turned out to be a duplicate! Doesn't quid know about the EoQS?